# Locking columns from deleting when using df_to_sheet in gspread_pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am using a gspread_pandas + internal library that helps me get data from sfdc and paste it into a G-Sheet that has columns A-N for data and O-Q has formulas working off on the data. This data needs to be updated daily and NOT appended in the sense that the code needs to clear info from Col A-N and replace it with the latest data.

The issue is that when the code runs it is removing EVERYTHING on my G-Sheet including O-Q which has formulas.

I am at a loss here because it is not feasible for me to keep the data and working sheets separately as this adds a lot of space pressure to the G-Sheet to have one sheet with data and another sheet with data+formulas.

Here is my code :

```
import pandas as pd
from gspread_pandas import Spread

import sys
sys.path.append("/files/apac")

import datascience_APAC as ds

data = ds.sfdcApi_to_pd("00O3a000004xr80")

wkbk = Spread("****@gmail.com", "1F1XUTuRTV6nLcTImDAuDTTWFpSVfUAKY7t3oElkhWBo")

wkbk.clear_sheet(sheet="Test")
time.sleep(5)
wkbk.df_to_sheet(data, index=False, replace=True, sheet="Test")
```

The issue here is that df_to_sheet has parameters that coerce it to start from a particular column and row but does not have a parameter for the number of columns to determine what to clear and therefore clears everything including my formulas.

Please help this newbie. :)

Comment: From the [`gspread_pandas`](https://gspread-pandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gspread_pandas.html#gspread_pandas.spread.Spread.df_to_sheet) docs it looks like df_to_sheet argument `replace=True` clears the sheet. Have you tried setting this to False?

Comment: @MichaelDelgado If I keep replace=False, then suppose I had 15 lines initially and after refreshing I have 10 lines then the data overwrites the first 10 lines but leaves the last 5 lines from before deeming the dataset incorrect

Comment: Ok - that seems like a different question. If you don't know how much of your google sheet you want to delete, this does indeed seem like a tough problem, but clearing the sheet when you request it isn't a `gspread_pandas` bug - it's a feature. The simplest solution does seem to be reconfiguring your workbook to draw data from an export-only sheet that you clear each time. Otherwise, you may need to try using [Google Apps Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets) to find the range to be cleared before exporting your data.

Answer (score 0):

I use .values_clear() from [gspread](https://docs.gspread.org/en/latest/api.html?highlight=values_clear#gspread.spreadsheet.Spreadsheet.values_clear) library :

```
#use your own credentials to login
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()

import gspread
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

gc = gspread.authorize(GoogleCredentials.get_application_default())

sh = gc.open_by_key("1F1XUTuRTV6nLcTImDAuDTTWFpSVfUAKY7t3oElkhWBo") #your file key 

sh.values_clear("Test!A:J") #example range, use your own as per need
```

Comment: Needs more clarity. Add a working solution and why you are doing what you are doing.